# How to isomorphically parse and remove cookies in nuxt 3?

Tags: cookies, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I know there are `h3` utilities like `parseCookie`, `removeCookie`, but these work only on the server. I also know `useCookie`, but that only allows to read one specific cookie. In my case I need to parse all cookies, filter them and delete specific cookies.
This is what ideally want to achieve:

```
// could happen on serve or client
const allCookies = getAllCookies() // get all cookies isomorphically 
for (const cookie of Object.keys(allCookies)) {
  if (cookie.startsWith("special-cookie")) {
    // isomoprhically delete cookie
    deleteCookie(cookie)
  }
}
```

I also found a solution from vueuse library (https://vueuse.org/integrations/useCookies/)  but i wouldn't want to install an extra dependency for this.
Does Nuxt 3 have isomorphic cookie handling?